# Starting Webrick inserts database record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, webrick

A very strange scenario that I've not come across before. When I start Webrick using `rails s`, a new database record is inserted for a model called `AbsenceCategory`.  Output from the terminal is:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-04-01 08:05:24] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-04-01 08:05:24] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-
darwin14.0.0]
[2015-04-01 08:05:24] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=81005 port=3000
```

Development.log shows the following:

```
[1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
[1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `absence_categories` (`description`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Annual Leave', '2015-04-01 07:07:03.369454', '2015-04-01 07:07:03.369454')
[1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
```

Before I drop the table, delete the model files and recreate everything, I thought I'd see if anyone has an insight into why this might be happening or what I can do to try and track down why.

Comment: I'd add a before_create callback with a call to byebug to the model

Comment: Could you please add your routes.rb ?